# Outlook 2007 client-only rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am trying to create a rule in outlook but the rule is automatically becoming client-only. How do I prevent it?

The rule actions are: Move messages to a folder & display an alert.

The rule works fine if I just configure moving messages to folder. But, when I set display alert, it becomes client-only. I have read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/101309/why-cant-my-outlook-2007-rule-be-server-side-when-using-mark-as-read-only-rul). But, at least moving messages to folder part should work with server as well.

I read somewhere that there is fixed size for outlook rules. Does this have anything to do with it? I have just 5 rules btw and one of them is becoming client-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is the same as the answer to the linked question.  If the rule is server-side, it is processed whether or not there is a client present and connected.  If you want to display an alert, then the client must be present, therefore it cannot be a server-side rule.

If you want it server-side, you cannot have an alert.  If you want an alert, you cannot have it server side.

Comment: cant the server execute the move messages to folder of my rule somehow?
because, this made me create 2 rules, 1 for moving messages and one just for displaying alert!

Comment: Yes the server can do the move it is a server side rule, and it cannot be a server side rule if it has a client actionable component such as displaying an alert.